# mysqli_num_rows() Error

Tags: php, mysqli

I am passing $query"UPDATE...", which has no errors, to a query method. I have checked other posts but they all point to the query which does not appear to be my problem.

```
   public function query($sql) {
        $this->_result = mysqli_query($this->_link, $sql);
        $this->_numRows = mysqli_num_rows($this->_result);
      }

   $db->numRows();
```

I am receiving the error 'mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in...', like i said there is nothing wrong with the query, _numRows is returning the correct value but the numRows() method which returns _numRows, is returning the error. Any ideas would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You said it yourself your are executing update query which does not return any rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*I am passing an `UPDATE` query..*"

Read the documentation for [`mysqli::query`](https://www.php.net/mysqli_query):

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. **For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.**

Hence no rows are returned (which is what `mysqli_num_rows` does). You're most likely looking for [`mysqli::$affected_rows`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) instead (that shows how many rows were *affected* - not how many rows were returned):

```
$this->_numRows = $this->_link->affected_rows;
```

or

```
$this->_numRows = mysqli_affected_rows($this->_link);
```